# BeautifulSoup can't find required div

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to get at a nested div and its contents but am not able to. I want to access the div with class:'box coursebox'. 
[image: source code of required section of page]

```
response = res.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")    
div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'box coursebox'})
```

The above code gives a div with 0 elements, when there should be 8. 
find_all calls before this line work perfectly.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: post url.........

Comment: The website is hosted only on my university's LAN and cant be accessed from outside. The image posted shows the required section of the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of attributes having more than one value, Beautiful Soup puts all the values into a list. In your code, you need to take this into account when you're doing your lookup.

Perhaps something like this?

```
div = soup.find_all('div', class_="box coursebox"})
```

Refer to [this section](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes) of Beautiful Soup's documentation for more information on multi-valued attributes, and [this section](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) for details on looking elements up by class.

Also, *please* don't post source code as an image.

Comment: Sorry for the image, I won't do it next time. Also, I have done exactly what you suggested in the source code above, please have a look at it. The image is of the required HTML of the web page, while the code written for scraping is below it.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
```

to:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
```

`html.parser` is not stable, you can change it to `lxml`

Comment: FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
_45cfeecd _dd3a8045
1