# BeautifulSoup - can't find attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this [link](https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/temetrius-morant-1.html).
I want to get to this part here:

[image]

I can see where this part of the website is when I inspect the page:
[image]

But I can't get to it from `BeautifulSoup`.
Here is the code that I'm using and all the ways I've tried to access it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/temetrius-morant-1.html'
html_text = requests.get(link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

soup.find_all(class_='data_grid')
soup.find_all(string="data_grid")
soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "data_grid"})
```

Also, when I just look at the `html` I can see that it is there:
[image]

Comment: That information is being rendered (not even pulled from an API) dynamically by Javascript in page, probably based on info from existing tables (didn't check). You can try Selenium, or you can try figuring the info out from the tables existent in initial HTML loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the actual source html code that you get in response (not the html you inspect, which you have shown to have done), you'll notice those tables are within the comments of the html Ie. `<!--` and `-->`. BeautifulSoup ignores comments.

There are a few ways to go about it. BeautifulSoup does have a method to search and pull out comments, however with this particular site, I find it just easier to remove the comment tags.

Once you do that, you can easily parse the html with BeautifulSoup to get the desired `<div>` tag, then just let `pandas` parse the `<table>` tag within there.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/temetrius-morant-1.html'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text
html = html.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
leaderboard_pts = soup.find('div', {'id':'leaderboard_pts'})

df = pd.read_html(str(leaderboard_pts))[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
                        0
0  2017-18 OVC 405 (18th)
1  2018-19 NCAA 808 (9th)
2   2018-19 OVC 808 (1st)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you re looking for the `point` section i suggest to search with `id` like this:

```
point_section=soup.find("div",{"id":"leaderboard_pts"})
```

Comment: same problem, doesn't find anything. 
It's almost as if I can't get into that whole section starting at `class = data_grid`. 
I actually just noticed that on the webpage, you sometimes have to click a little widget to see all those numbers. But I can still see that section in my html output

Comment: @jmich738 there is some strange behaviour for div lookup and you have to specify class in form `class_="data_grid"` in `soup.find_all`. More details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097894/beautifulsoup-cant-find-required-div